# How can I use OR constraint with multiple semi-joins?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I implement the below SQL using semijoin in either SparkSQL or Dataframe API?

```
select * 
from foo
left join a on foo.id = a.id
left join b on foo.id = b.id
where exists (select 1 from a x where foo.id = x.id)
or exists (select 1 from b x where foo.id = x.id)
;
```

I have tried this but it functions as AND

```
.join(loincDF, foo("id") <=> a("id"), "leftsemi")
.join(loincDF, foo("id") <=> b("id"), "leftsemi")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
foo.join(a, Seq("id"), "leftsemi")
   .union( foo.join(b, Seq("id"), "leftsemi") )
   .distinct
```

Comment: is there any way to do this without a distinct? I have quite a few columns and lots of rows

Comment: Sure you can do that: you could do 2 leftouter joins and then check if at least one of the columns of a or b that are added to foo in this way exist. so after (leftouter-)joining you basically filter those rows that have either a.X or b.Y present.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in @Elmar Macek's solution, a union of the `left_semi` joins mimics the `OR` condition of the `exists` clauses.  However, `left_semi` join does not produce corresponding columns from the `right` DataFrame.  To generate result equivalent to your SQL which involves `left join`s, you can first perform `left_outer` joins before applying the filtering logic that mimics the `exists` function.

Below are a couple of methods:

METHOD 1: Perform `left_outer` joins, then `left_semi` joins

```scala
val foo = Seq(
  (1, "f1"), (2, "f2"), (3, "f3"), (4, "f4"), (5, "f5")
).toDF("id", "name")

val a = Seq(
  (1, "a1"), (3, "a3")
).toDF("id", "desc")

val b = Seq(
  (1, "b1"), (4, "b4")
).toDF("id", "desc")

val bar = foo.
  join(a, Seq("id"), "left_outer").
  join(b, Seq("id"), "left_outer")

bar.join(a, Seq("id"), "left_semi").
  union(
    bar.join(b, Seq("id"), "left_semi")
  ).
  distinct.
  show
// +---+----+----+----+
// | id|name|desc|desc|
// +---+----+----+----+
// |  4|  f4|null|  b4|
// |  1|  f1|  a1|  b1|
// |  3|  f3|  a3|null|
// +---+----+----+----+
```

METHOD 2: Perform `left_outer` joins, then `null` checks on the non-key columns

```scala
val aNonKeyCols = a.columns.filter(_ != "id")
val a2 = a.withColumn("aCols", struct(aNonKeyCols.map(col): _*)).
  select("id", "aCols")

val bNonKeyCols = b.columns.filter(_ != "id")
val b2 = b.withColumn("bCols", struct(aNonKeyCols.map(col): _*)).
  select("id", "bCols")

val bar = foo.
  join(a2, Seq("id"), "left_outer").
  join(b2, Seq("id"), "left_outer").
  where($"aCols".isNotNull || $"bCols".isNotNull).
  select("id", "name", "aCols.*", "bCols.*")
```

Note that, with the assumption that there may be many columns, the non-key columns of `a` and `b` are each placed in a `struct` so as to simplify the `null` check.

Comment: is there any way to do this without a distinct? I have quite a few columns and lots of rows

Comment: @Josh, please see my expanded answer which consists of an alternative method.